# Як перекласти з англійської фразу Шекспіра з трагедії «Ромео та Джульєтта», "These violent delights have violent ends"

Tags: переклад, from-english

Як перекласти українською фразу Шекспіра з трагедії «Ромео та Джульєтта» (Акт 2, Сцена 6)

> "These violent delights have violent ends".

У своїй відповіді бажано використовувати приклади того як цей вираз переклали українські перекладачі (мені відомо про 6 перекладів (якщо вважати 2 редакції перекладу Куліша зроблені Франком та Вороним як неокремі переклади) + існує ненадрукований переклад Гната Хоткевича що зберігається у ЦДІА України у Львові).

Мене цікавить саме цей вираз, бо його часто згадують у 1-шому та 2-ому сезонах телесеріалу HBO "Західний світ" / "Westworld" й наявний український переклад цього виразу від UATeam/НеЗупиняйПродакшн мене не задовольняє. Вони переклали цю фразу як

> "Жорстким пристрастям жорсткий кінець" (UATeam) [джерело](http://web.archive.org/web/20180224154610/https://kino-teatr.ua/public/main/films/trailer_10139.mp4)
>
> "У жорстоких насолод - жорстокий фінал" (НеЗупиняйПродакшн) [джерело](https://toloka.to/t89581)

Comment: Заувага: ідеальна відповідь міститиме всі наявні 6 українських перекладів.

Comment: А навіщо вам ідеальна відповідь? Он уже 4 переклади знайшли, то що, як ще дві людини кожна знайде по перекладу й кожна його тут напише, й разом вже буде всі шість, то ви будете невдоволені?

Comment: @YellowSky хмм, слушне зауваження. Але як я й сказав вище, навпаки, всіма 6ма перекладами я буду надзвичайно вдоволеним.

Comment: @piznajko, перепрошую, але якщо Ви самі всі 6 перекладів знаєте, то чому самі їх і не напишете?

Comment: Я всі 6 не знаю. Я знаю де прочитать Про всі 6, але до самих перекладів доступу немає

Comment: @piznajko, зрозуміло. P.S.: відповідаючи в коментарях, добре вказувати адресата через знак «@» (он як я Вас на початку цього коментаря); бо сповіщення про новий коментар отримує лише автор запитання/відповіді (його, відповідно, можна не вказувати) і той, до кого прямо звернулися через «@» (інші автоматично про новий коментар не дізнаються).

Comment: @Sasha У HathiTrust теж є цей скан (я його раніше бачив) - https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/006609354 . Але там теж можна лише шукати вирази, а оскільки я не знаю як саме Костецький переклав це речення то й пошук здається неможливим.

Comment: Ну, насправді нема такого правила, щоби обов'язково «окремо запитання українською — окремо англійською». По-моєму, навіть навпаки — краще мати обидві версії в одному місці. Але Ви, як автор запитання, звісно, можете відкидати будь-які редагування / пропозиції щодо редагування у Вашій відповіді (типу, за Вами останнє слово).

Comment: @Sasha Переклад англійською був трохи а-ля Ґуґл транслейт. Такого робити не треба.

Comment: @piznajko, можливо. Користувач, що його робив (FracturedRetina, це видно в [історії](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/posts/1182/revisions)) не володіє українською мовою на 100%.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

«Ромео та Джульєтта» в перекладі Ігоря Костецького (1957, видавництво «На горі»):

> [*[Брат Лаврін:]* Палкії втіхи жде палкий кінець. Тріюмф їх — смерть їх.](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%96%D1%97+%D0%B2%D1%82%D1%96%D1%85%D0%B8+%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C+%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8E%D0%BC%D1%84+%D1%97%D1%85+%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%97%D1%85")

Comment: Дякую! Джерело скан [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=iz5AAAAAIAAJ&hl=uk&source=gbs_navlinks_s)?

Comment: @piznajko, так. Ну, точніше, розпізнані фрагменти з цього скану в сніпетах результатів пошуку. Бо переглянути саме цей фрагмент цього скану Google Books не дозволяє.

Comment: Прияняв відповідь від @Sasha, бо реально було надзвичайно важко знайти переклад РіД Костецького й кількість часу та зусиль які на це витратив Sasha викликають справжню повагу. Дяки!!!

пс. Ну й звичайно ж дякую Palacsinta та Yellow Sky за решту варіантів перекладів.

Answer (score 19):

- Переклад Пантелеймона Куліша (Львів, 1901, [стор. 59](http://shron.chtyvo.org.ua/William_Shakespeare/Romeo_ta_Dzhulieta.pdf)):

> Завзяті радощі кінчають ся завзяттєм;

- У перекладі Ірини Стешенко (Шекспір В. Твори в шести томах [Т. 2], 1985, стор. 357) це звучить так:

> Бурхливі радощі страшні, мій сину,
>   Бо часто в них бурхливий і кінець.

- У перекладі Василя Мисика (журнал «Прапор», 1988, №№9–10), це звучить так:

> Ці буйні радощі й кінчаться буйно —

Вибачте, та инших перекладів я не зміг знайти.

---

- Translated by Panteleimon Kulish (Lviv, 1901, [p. 59](http://shron.chtyvo.org.ua/William_Shakespeare/Romeo_ta_Dzhulieta.pdf)):

> Завзяті радощі кінчають ся завзяттєм;

- Translated by Iryna Steshenko (W. Shakespeare's works in six volumes [Vol. 2], 1985, p. 357) it sounds like:

> Бурхливі радощі страшні, мій сину,
>   Бо часто в них бурхливий і кінець.

- Translated by Wasyl Mysyk ("Prapor" magazine, 1988, №9–10), it sounds like:

> Ці буйні радощі й кінчаться буйно —

I couldn't find the other translations.

Comment: Замінив джерело перекладу Стешенко на той де переклад з'явився вперше (Вільям Шекспір. Вибрані твори: В 2 т. Київ: Мистецтво. Т. 1.[4] 1950. 801 стор.), але бачу ви це редагування відкинули.

Comment: Також переклад Куліша 1901, це не просто його переклад, а переклад у редакції Івана Франка (це моє редагування бачу ви відкинули теж)

Comment: @piznajko - Я знайшов ці цитати у сканах _реальних_ книжок і я вказую ті дані, які саме в них були написані. Як ваша фраза звучала в перекладі Стешенко в виданні 1950 р. я просто _не знаю_, бо я знайшов лише видання 1985 р. Те саме й з Кулішем. Ніякого «Панька» та «за редакцією Франка» там не значилося, Франко там написав передмову та коментарі, от і все. Я пишу лише правду, нічого домислювати або видавати бажане за дійсне я не збираюся.

Comment: Редакції Стешенко між 1952 та 1985 не змінилися.

пс. Раджу озайомитися хоч похапцем з _Олексин, Ольга.  [Особливості відтворення шекспірової гри слів в українських перекладах: дисертація кандидата філологічних наук](http://web.archive.org/web/20170401193503/http://www.kspu.edu/FileDownload.ashx/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F.doc?id=eb023654-93f5-41f6-83ae-746b20e158b5) // Львів: Львівський Національний Університет Імені Івана Франка, 2016. 229 стор._

Звідти ви дізнаєтесь про 2 редакції перекладу Франка

Comment: @piznajko - Як ви це знаєте? Читали обидва видання? То чому тоді просите инших вам цитату знайти? А оте читати не буду, мене переклади Шекспіра не цікавлять, вони всі спотворюють його ґеніальну поезію.

Comment: Знаю що різниці між редакціями перекладу Стешенко немає між виданнями 1952 та 1985 років бо так каже перекладацька наукова література

Comment: Панько він і в Африці Панько. Куліш сам надавав перевагу цій димунітивній формі свого імені і підписував так свої літературні праці. До речі, якщо не хочете ознайомитися зі 229-сторінковою роботою Оликсиної, [ось тут](http://philology.knu.ua/library/zagal/Movni_i_konceptualni_2011_38/347_359.pdf) (стор. 355) згадується про редакцію переклада Панька Куліша зроблену Вороним; а [ось тут](http://molodyvcheny.in.ua/files/journal/2016/4/99.pdf) (стор. 407) Олексин у своїй статті згадує про редакцію Кулішевого перекладу зроблену Франком.

Comment: @piznajko - Ось вам мій [ориґинал](http://shron.chtyvo.org.ua/William_Shakespeare/Romeo_ta_Dzhulieta.pdf). Скажіть, от де там «Панько», де там «під редакцією Франка»? Я ж вам вже написав, хіба одного разу вам мало? Чи ще й втретє доведеться писати?

Answer (score 14):

У перекладі Юрія Андруховича (2016) все, як завжди, зовсім не так:

> "Пориви згубні, бо поривно гинуть"

Є ще переклади Панька Куліша у редакції Миколи Вороного (1928), Абрама Гозенпуда (1937) та Ігоря Костецького (1957), але, здається, час поглинув їх.

Comment: Дякую! Якщо вважати дві редакції перекладу Панька Куліша, то тоді ще є переклад Куліша у редакції Миколи Вороного (1928)